# What is the history of the multichannel analyzer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, history

I'm doing a presentation over multichannel analyzers and one of the topics is "A Brief History of Multichannel Analyzers" and I am having great difficulty finding anything on the subject. I have done extensive online searching and have come out with nothing. I haven't had a chance to make it to a library but I am doubtful one would have much information either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much all.

Comment: May or may not be off topic here, but have you considered the EE stack for this question?

Comment: I had not actually, I'm relatively new to SE so I wasn't sure of the best place to ask. My presenation is for my physics class so I figured this was the best place but I will try that one! Thank you!

Comment: Review of Scientific Instruments and Nuclear Instruments and Methods might be good places to search.